# Create a loop with if query in xsl fo

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to iterate through attributes in **XSL FO** using a loop, separating them with commas, except for the last element. I've read some posts here, but somehow it doesn't work for me.

**This is an example of how my code is structured:**

**XML:**

```
<artikeldaten>
<artikel id="">
    <attribute>
        <attribut>a++</attribut>
        <attribut>75 Zoll</attribut>  
        <attribut>4k Ultra HD</attribut>  
        <attribut>UE75RU7179</attribut>  
        <attribut>37,5 kg</attribut>
        <attribut>154 Watt</attribut>
        <attribut>3x HDMI (digital)</attribut>
    </attribute>
</artikeldaten>
```

**XSL FO:**

```
<xs:template match="/">
 <fo:root>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4">
   <fo:flow flow-name="content">
    <fo:block-container>
     <fo:block>
      <xs:for-each select="artikeldaten/artikel/attribute">
       <xs:if test="position()!= last()">
        <xs:value-of select="."/>
         <xs:text>, </xs:text>
       </xs:if>
      </xs:for-each>
     </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
    //Closing tags
```

The solution is generally plausible for me, but unfortunately it does not work.

And yes, I have also already tested to place the value-of-function outside the if query.

How do I create the query correctly in XSL FO?

Comment: Is that simply a spelling/typo issue? The XML has elements named `attribut` (which would be German singular form), the select tries to select elements named `attribute` (with a trailing `e` which is English spelling or German plural form.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, but that is correct. In German, the plural of attribute is "Attribute". It's a bit confusing. The singular is "Attribut".

Comment: Yes, but the XPath expression has to match the spelling of the XML element name, your XML has elements named `attribut`, so the XPath expression to select them needs to use `attribut` as well and not `attribute` as you have done in the `select`of the `for-each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path seems to lack the last step to select the elements named `attribut`:

```
xs:for-each select="artikeldaten/artikel/attribute/attribut"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Thanks for your input. Then you mean you think the value-of-function should go out?

Comment: So I now have the value of element outside the if query. This works as well, but the if-query will not run. Is it perhaps because of the Tag <Text>?